# Maintaining Order of data in Pig Script

Tags: apache-pig

Let's say I have the following PIG Script

```
    record = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage('\t') as (id, name, age);
    orderedRecord = ORDER record BY age ASC;
    finalRecord = FOREACH orderedRecord GENERATE id,name;
    storedRecords = LIMIT finalRecord 1000;
    STORE storedRecords INTO 'output';
```

I know orderedRecord will be sorted based on age, but when I removed age from orderedRecord, does the data still in sorted order. I just want to store 1000 data points with just id and name sorted on the age.

Comment: I have got the answer : In order to have storeRecords in sorted order I should do the following >   record = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage('\t') as (id, name, age);
    orderedRecord = ORDER record BY age ASC;
    finalRecord = LIMIT finalRecord 1000;
    storedRecords = FOREACH orderedRecord GENERATE id,name; 
    STORE storedRecords INTO 'output';

Answer (score 0):

No, It may remain sorted as per my understanding but it is not guaranteed.

As you know if you further process this data then you will loose the order. So it is not guaranteed that your data will remain sorted but chances of it remaining ordered are still there.

Comment: I know for sure that if I do